# Splitting a number pattern

Tags: python, string, algorithm

I want to now how do i split a string like
`44664212666666 into [44664212 , 666666]` or
`58834888888888 into [58834, 888888888]`
without knowing where the first occurrence of the last recurring digit occurs.
so passing it to a function say `seperate(str)` --> `[non_recurring_part, end_recurring digits]`

Comment: i tried getting last_dig = number[-1] and doing a split() of that number.. and ignoring all members of length 1 in the list.

Comment: [Longest common substring](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring#Python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print re.findall(r'^(.+?)((.)\3+)$', '446642126666')[0][:-1] # ('44664212', '6666')
```

As pointed out in the comments, the last group should be made optional to handle strings with no repeated symbols correctly:

```
print re.findall(r'^(.+?)((.)\3+)?$', '12333')[0][:-1] # ('12', '333')
print re.findall(r'^(.+?)((.)\3+)?$', '123')[0][:-1]   # ('123', '')
```

Comment: What if there are no recurring digits?

Comment: `^(.+?)((.)\3+)?$` can perfectly deal with no recurring digits. Note `?` before `$`.

Comment: @J0HN: `?` here is fof non-greedy search. That has nothing to do with recurring digits

Comment: @IgorChubin, thanks, cap. That's exactly why it's there: if no recurring digits appear, the line without `?` throws an exception `IndexError: list index out of range`. With `?` it just an empty string, just like in Steven Rumbalski's answer.

Comment: @J0HN: Sorry, I didn't notice the version in comments. I mean the re in the answer. And here, in comments, `?` is not for greedy search. That means I'm not cap :)

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as Justin:

```
>>> for i in range(len(s) - 1, 0, -1):
    if s[i] != s[-1]:
        break


>>> non_recurring_part, end_recurring_digits = s[:i], s[i + 1:]
>>> non_recurring_part, end_recurring_digits
('4466421', '666666')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-regex answer that deals with cases when there are no repeating digits.

```
def separate(s):
    last = s[-1]
    t = s.rstrip(last)
    if len(t) + 1 == len(s):
        return (s, '')
    else:
        return t, last * (len(s) - len(t))
```

Examples:

```
>>> separate('123444')
('123', '444')
>>> separate('1234')
('1234', '')
>>> separate('11111')
('', '11111')
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just scan from the last character to the first character and stop when the next char doesn't equal the previous. Then split at that index.

Answer (score 0):

```
def separate(n):
    s = str(n)
    return re.match(r'^(.*?)((.)\3*)$', s).groups()
```

Comment: What if there are no recurring digits?  Also, it returns one group too many: `separate('12344')` => `('123', '44', '4')`

Answer (score 0):

```
def seperate(s):
 return re.findall('^(.+?)('+s[-1]+'+)$',s)
```

Comment: What if there are no recurring digits? `seperate('1234')` => `[('123', '4')]`

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski I think the assumption is that there are only strings with multiple the same digits at the end.

Comment: Fair enough.  I assumed otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.match(r'(.*?)((.)\3+)$', '1233333')
>>> print list(m.groups())[:2]
['12', '33333']
```

Here you use regular expressions. The last part of the re `((.)\3+)$` says that the same number must be repeated till the end of the string. And all the rest is the first part of the string. The function `m.groups()` return the list of the string that correspond to the `()` parts of the re. The 0 element contains the first part; the 1 element contains the second part. The third part is not needed, we can just ignore it.

Another important point is `?` in `.*?`. Using the symbol you say that you need non-greedy search. That means that you need to switch to the second part of re as soon as possible.

Comment: What if there are no recurring digits?

Comment: Just replace `+` with `*` and the last digit will be considered as recurring.

Answer (score 0):

start iterating from the end,towards the initial digit, just get the position where the character occurring changes, that should be the limit for sub string splitting, Let that limit index is--> i, Then Your Result will be-->{sub-string [0,i) , sub-string [i,size)},, That will solve your problem..

```
         int pos=0;
    String str="ABCDEF";
    for (int i = str.length()-1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if(str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i-1))
        {
            pos=i;
            break;
        }
    }

    String sub1=str.substring(0, pos);
    String sub2=str.substring(pos);
```